# Convert xva (citrix xenserver) image to .img (vanilla xen) image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud, virtualization, xen

I am looking if there is any tried and tested way to convert Citrix xenserver .xva file to vanilla xen .img file?

Tried "qemu-img convert -O raw" option but that didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the .xva format:

```
it's a tar file
it contains a folder
the folder contains chunks of 1MB each
they can be concatenated, but blank space needs to be filled
```

Please follow

http://wiki.sysconfig.org.uk/display/howto/Convert+Citrix+XenServer+images+to+plain+Xen